# duel boot problem windows 8 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I successfully installed UBUNTU 12.04 on a pre installed windows 8 laptop, but when I try to boot windows 8 I receive next problem:

Error: Secure Boot forbids loading module from (hd0, gpt6)/boot/grup/ntfs.mod

Error: no such device: FEBE18858BE186605,

Error: unknown command 'drivemap'

Error: invalid EFI file path.

Press any key to continue...

I can only boot windows 8 properly when I use F12 and choose the special windows 8 boot manager.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the secure boot option?  It is an option in the UEFI settings.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481258.aspx  should explain how to do this.

Afterwords if there is a watermark warning in the bottom right corner about secure boot Microsoft has released a fix that removes it.

This should be the fix. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2902864

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it dind't help. The secure option was already disabled and I have never noticed a watermark warning.